# Resultset logic when selecting tables without a join?

Tags: sql, oracle, resultset

Dumb question..  what logic does the database use to determine the result set if you do a select without a join such as:

```
select * from table1, table2
```

Comment: Just a semantic quibble: your select WILL join the tables. The "," operator is considered to be a synonym for CROSS JOIN (also known as cartesian join, as Ferreria has said).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It uses a [cartesian product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product), it gives every possible combination of the two tables.

[More info on this, applied to SQL.](http://www.fluffycat.com/SQL/Cartesian-Joins/)

Answer (score 5):

Cartesian product.  Each row in table one is matched up to each row in table two.